# Confused on wether i need a sentinal value to terminate my do while loop to allow for more than one entry

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am to use a do while loop to print out the average grade and letter grade, but then i am asked to use another loop to allow for more than one grade to be determined.

My problem is i am getting an infinite loop with my do while loop and im not sure when i need to terminate it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float avgscore;
    int count;

    cout << "Please enter enter your average score inpercent format. I.E. 95.6%" << endl;
    cin >> avgscore;

    do
    {
        if (avgscore >= 90)
        cout << "Your exam score is: " << avgscore << " Which results in the grade an A!"<<endl;

        else if (avgscore >= 80)
            cout << "Your exam score is: " << avgscore << " Which results in the grade of a B!" << endl;

        else if (avgscore >= 70)
            cout << "Your exam score is: " << avgscore << " Which results in the grade of a C!" << endl;

        else if (avgscore >= 60)
            cout << "Your exam score is: " << avgscore << " Which results in the grade of a D!" << endl;

        else if (avgscore <= 59.9)
            cout << "Your exam score is: " << avgscore << " Which results in the grade of a F!" << endl;
    }
    while (avgscore > 0); //This is my problem here, but i'm not sure what i need here to end it.
    // I need to add another loop here to allow for more than one entry.

    return 0;
}
```

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put the following lines

```
cout << "Please enter enter your average score inpercent format. I.E. 95.6%" << endl;
cin >> avgscore;
```

inside the `do-while` to be able to derminate the loop by inputting a value that is `<=0`.

The key idea here is **you need to have the ability to change the `avgscore`'s value inside the loop** so that the checking condition will because `false` if you want.

Comment: this still brings me into an infinite loop. I need to figure out how to make it false after the entry is entered.

Comment: @user3312523 You need to input a value that is `<=0`, e.g. `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a logical problem here.  Your user inputs `avgscore` before going into the loop and then you try to loop on it, where it has no chance to change.

You need to restructure it so that your user can put its input in and then it can loop based on that input.

pseudocode:

```
do {
    //ask for input
    cout << "Please enter enter your average score inpercent format. I.E. 95.6%" << endl;
    cin >> avgscore;

    //Print stuff based on input

    //ask if they want to do another 
    cout <<"want to do another? Enter 'n' to exit"<<endl;

    cin >> continue;
} while ( continue != "n");

cout<<"exiting..."<<endl;

//Note:  Syntax on all this is way off as I haven't been writing c++ lately.
```

Comment: Looks like this is your first answer. Congrats! When posting code, please click on the orange ? when you are editing. It will tell you how to mark the code sections as code.

Comment: Thank everyone for their input i have it figured out now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to move your `do` to enclose the input.

```
float avgscore = 0.0; //always initialize
int count = 0; //always initialize

do
{
    std::cout << "Please enter enter your average score in percent format. I.E. 95.6%"
        << " (enter 0 to end)" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> avgscore;
    //if statements
} while (avgscore > 0);
```

This will loop until the user enters 0, but for each time until then it will output the score and the letter grade.